# Determining if *char < INT_MAX

Tags: c

I got this code:

```
char a[151];
scanf ("%150s", a);
```

In `a` could be a number and if so, I need to determine, if `a < INT_MAX`. I don't know, how to do that, because in each index of `a` char could be a number, it means 150-digit number which could cause overflow if I store a value into some int or anything else. Any suggestions?

Comment: Maybe use a `int *` and allocate memory to it but that maybe too much memory allocation .

Comment: `char a[150];` **->** `char a[151];`.

Comment: why not a[150]? first character has index 0 or am I wrong?

Comment: You want to store `150` digit number and using `%s` , you need to leave space for `null character` .

Comment: From 0 to 149 are 150 "places" and on 150th index is null character, isn't it?

Comment: `0 to 149` are `150` places . There is no `150` th index for you then. That why declare with `151` elements .

Comment: Thanks for clarification :)

Comment: Look at http://blog.regehr.org/archives/914 . It is full of solutions to your problem.

Comment: Edge case.  Detect `if a < INT_MAX`.  Hmm. Should not that be `if a <= INT_MAX`? `<` vs `<=`?

Answer (score 2):

Call `strtol()` and test `errno`.

> If the correct value is outside the range of representable values, `LONG_MIN`, `LONG_MAX`, ...  the value of the macro `ERANGE` is stored in `errno`.  C11dr §7.22.1.4 8

```
char a[151];
scanf ("%150s", a);
char *endptr;
errno = 0;
long num = strtol(a, &endptr, 10);
if (errno == ERANGE) Overflow();  // outside `long` range
if (num > INT_MAX) Overflow();    // greater than `INT_MAX`
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve:

```
1. INT_MAX = 2147483647 --> contains 10 digits  
2. len = strlen(a);  
3. if (len > 10)   
   a. true --> then a > INT_MAX --> print answer and return  
   b. false, go to step 4  
4. if (len < 10)  
   a. true --> then a < INT_MAX --> print answer and return  
   b. false, go to step 5  
5. (len == 10) case  
6. if (a[9]-'0' > 2) // 10th digit is > 2  
   a. true --> then a > INT_MAX --> print answer and return  
   b. false, go to step 7  
7. int num = atoi(a);  
9. Compare num and INT_MAX and print answer and return
```

[NOTE: Negative numbers not considered here]

Comment: What if `a == '2147483644'` ? And what if `INT_MAX` has another value, it shouldn't be `INT32_MAX`. I mean it souldn't be ran on 32bit pc

Comment: Note: This method declares inputs like `"00000000000001" as overflow.

Comment: I agree with the two inputs, it will fail my algorithm. @chux, your suggested solution is good one.

Comment: Should I delete this post since it is not correct? Or someone please downvote it.